# problem with NoReverseMatch in Python(Django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I created a website based on Django, and clicking on the trash displays an error. I can't understand what this is related to. I understand that there is not much information, but if you have any suggestions about what this is related to, please tell me!
I attach the error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7mob.png)

---

Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\User\Desktop\sex\PythonShopDjango\shop\mainapp\templates\base.html, error at line 35

Reverse for 'change_qty' with keyword arguments '{'ct_model': '', 'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['change\-qty/(?P<ct_model>[^/]+)/(?P[^/]+)/$']

```
26  </style>
27  <body>
28  
29    <!-- Navigation -->
30    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
31      <div class="container">
32        <div class="sign-wrap-4">
33            <div class="sign_word">O<span>a</span>s<span>i</span><span>s</span></div>
34        </div>
35        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
36          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
37        </button>
38        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
39          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
40            <li class="nav-item">
41              <a class="nav-link" style="color: #fffafa" href="{% url  'cart' %}">Корзина<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
42    <path d="M0 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 1H2a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.379L2.89 3H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .491.592l-1.5 8A.5.5 0 0 1 13 12H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.491-.408L2.01 3.607 1.61 2H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM3.102 4l1.313 7h8.17l1.313-7H3.102zM5 12a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm7 0a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm-7 1a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm7 0a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2z"/>
43  </svg><span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">{{ cart.products.count }}</span></a>
44            </li>
45          </ul>
```

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (BaseView, ProductDetailView, CategoryDetailView, CartView, AddToCartView, DeleteFromCartView,
                    ChangeQTYView, CheckoutView, MakeOrderView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', BaseView.as_view(), name='base'),
    path('products/<str:ct_model>/<str:slug>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product_detail'),
    path('category/<str:slug>/', CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='category_detail'),
    path('cart/', CartView.as_view(), name='cart'),
    path('add-to-cart/<str:ct_model>/<str:slug>/', AddToCartView.as_view(), name='add_to_cart'),
    path('remove-from-cart/<str:ct_model>/<str:slug>/', DeleteFromCartView.as_view(), name='delete_from_cart'),
    path('change-qty/<str:ct_model>/<str:slug>/', ChangeQTYView.as_view(), name='change_qty'),
    path('checkout/',CheckoutView.as_view(), name='checkout'),
    path('make-order/',MakeOrderView.as_view(), name='make_order')
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import DetailView, View
from .models import Notebook, Smartphone, Category, LatestProducts, Customer, Cart, CartProduct
from .mixins import CategoryDetailMixin, CartMixin
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import OrderForm
from .utils import recalc_cart
from django.db import transaction




class BaseView(CartMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        categories = Category.objects.get_categories_for_left_sidebar()
        products = LatestProducts.objects.get_products_for_main_page('notebook', 'smartphone',
                                                                     with_respect_to='notebook', )
        context = {
            'categories': categories,
            'products': products,
            'cart': self.cart

        }
        return render(request, 'base.html', context)


class ProductDetailView(CartMixin, CategoryDetailMixin, DetailView):
    CT_MODEL_CLASS = {
        'notebook': Notebook,
        'smartphone': Smartphone,
    }

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.model = self.CT_MODEL_CLASS[kwargs['ct_model']]
        self.queryset = self.model._base_manager.all()
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    context_object_name = 'product'
    template_name = 'product_detail.html'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['ct_model'] = self.model._meta.model_name
        context['cart'] = self.cart
        return context


class CategoryDetailView(CartMixin, CategoryDetailMixin, DetailView):
    model = Category
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'category'
    template_name = 'category_detail.html'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cart'] = self.cart
        return context


class AddToCartView(CartMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ct_model, product_slug = kwargs.get('ct_model'), kwargs.get('slug')

        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=ct_model)
        product = content_type.model_class().objects.get(slug=product_slug)
        cart_product, created = CartProduct.objects.get_or_create(
            user=self.cart.owner, cart=self.cart, content_type=content_type, object_id=product.id,
        )
        if created:
            self.cart.products.add(cart_product)
        recalc_cart(self.cart)
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Товар добавлен!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/cart/')


class DeleteFromCartView(CartMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ct_model, product_slug = kwargs.get('ct_model'), kwargs.get('slug')
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=ct_model)
        product = content_type.model_class().objects.get(slug=product_slug)
        cart_product = CartProduct.objects.get(
            user=self.cart.owner, cart=self.cart, content_type=content_type, object_id=product.id,
        )

        self.cart.products.remove(cart_product)
        cart_product.delete()
        recalc_cart(self.cart)
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Товар удален!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/cart/')


class ChangeQTYView(CartMixin, View):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ct_model, product_slug = kwargs.get('ct_model'), kwargs.get('slug')
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=ct_model)
        product = content_type.model_class().objects.get(slug=product_slug)
        cart_product = CartProduct.objects.get(
            user=self.cart.owner, cart=self.cart, content_type=content_type, object_id=product.id,
        )
        qty = int(request.POST.get('qty'))
        cart_product.qty = qty
        cart_product.save()
        recalc_cart(self.cart)
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Вы успешно изменили количество!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/cart/')


class CartView(CartMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        categories = Category.objects.get_categories_for_left_sidebar()
        context = {
            'cart': self.cart,
            'categories': categories,
        }
        return render(request, 'cart.html', context)


class CheckoutView(CartMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        categories = Category.objects.get_categories_for_left_sidebar()
        form = OrderForm(request.POST or None)
        context = {
            'cart': self.cart,
            'categories': categories,
            'form': form
        }
        return render(request, 'checkout.html', context)


class MakeOrderView(CartMixin, View):
    @transaction.atomic
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = OrderForm((request.POST or None))
        customer =  Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_order = form.save(commit=False)
            new_order.customer = customer
            new_order.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            new_order.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            new_order.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            new_order.address = form.cleaned_data['address']
            new_order.buying_type = form.cleaned_data['buying_type']
            new_order.order_date = form.cleaned_data['order_date']
            new_order.comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            new_order.save()
            self.cart.in_order = True
            self.cart.save()
            new_order.cart = self.cart
            new_order.save()
            customer.orders.add(new_order)
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Спасибо за ваш заказ! Скоро с вами свяжутся')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/checkout/')
```

cart.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h3 class="text=center mt-5 mb-5">Ваша корзина {% if not cart.products.count %} пуста {% endif %}</h3>
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
      <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ message }}</strong>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% if cart.products.count %}
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Наименование</th>
      <th scope="col">Изображение</th>
      <th scope="col">Цена</th>
      <th scope="col">Кол-во</th>
      <th scope="col">Общая цена</th>
      <th scope="col">Действие</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {% for item in cart.products.all %}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{ item.content_object.title }}</th>
      <td class="w-25"><img src="{{ item.content_object.image.url }}" class="image-fluid"></td>
      <td>{{ item.content_object.price }} сом.</td>
      <td>
        <form action="{% url 'change_qty' ct_model=item.content_object.get_model_name slug=item.content_object.slug %}" method="POST">
           {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="number" class="form-control" name="qty" style="width:70px" min="1" value="{{ item.qty }}">
          <br>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Изменить кол-во">
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>{{ item.final_price }} сом.</td>
      <td>
        <a href="{% url 'delete_from_cart'  ct_model=item.content_object.get_model_name slug=item.content_object.slug %}"><button class="btn btn-danger">Удалить из корзины</button> </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
     <tr>
       <td colspan="2"></td>
       <td>Итого: </td>
       <td>{{ cart.total_products }}</td>
       <td><strong>{{ cart.final_price }} сом</strong></td>
       <td><a href="{% url 'checkout' %}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Перейти к оформлению</button></a></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: can you share your `urls.py` file? It looks to me as if you've mismatch a hyphen somewhere, e.g., `change_qty` vs. `change-qty`, but I'd need to see your `urls.py` to be able to tell.

Comment: I add urls.py bro

Comment: @АлманбетТотоев show your `CartView` and its template...

Comment: would you also mind sharing your `views.py`? I'm guessing you're doing something like `reverse('change_qty', args=['', ''])` when it should be `reverse('change-qty', args=['', ''])`

Comment: @brno32 i did it

Comment: bro @brno32 help me please!

Comment: I think @AbdulAzizBarkat is right. The error must be in the HTML template for `CartView`. Can you share `cart.html`?

Comment: yes, I did it @brno32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing in kwargs, but I think the `url` tag in templates only works with args.

In `cart.html`, try passing in positional args instead

```html
{% url 'change_qty' item.content_object.get_model_name item.content_object.slug %}
```